# Return count of patients residing in a unit per hour during date range using in and out datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a PatientCensus table that holds the following sample data:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PatientID | Unit | InDate                  | OutDate                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 100  | 2012-05-20 21:56:00.000 | 2012-06-30 08:10:00.000 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2         | 150  | 2012-05-20 22:16:00.000 | 2012-06-15 08:18:00.000 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to return a count of patients per hour for the date range that gets passed to the procedure. So for example, if the start range was Jan 1, 2012 at 12:00 AM and the end date was Jan 1, 2012 at 3:00 AM, I want it to look something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Unit | 2012-01-01 00:00 | 2012-01-01 01:00 | 2012-01-01 02:00 | 2012-01-01 03:00 | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 100  |        25        |        21        |        12        |        12        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 150  |        15        |        11        |        12        |        11        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm open to better ways to get this result as well. Thanks.

Comment: What is the rule for handling partial hours?   If an InDate or OutDate occurs in the middle of an hour?

Comment: Essentially, it should just truncate the minutes.

Comment: It's going to be tedious, you'll need to use a WHILE loop to build a dynamic sql query.

Comment: sounds like just a dynamic pivot with a recursive cte to build the time columns and to get the counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can get what you need using a dynamic pivot.

First thing I'd do is create a temp table with all of the hours between my start and end time.  You can use a recursive cte to do this.

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = '2012-06-01 00:00:00',
        @EndTime DATETIME = '2012-06-01 03:00:00'
;

WITH HourlyCTE AS
(
    SELECT  @StartTime AS StartTime,
            DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @StartTime) EndTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, 1, StartTime),
            CASE WHEN DATEADD(HOUR, 1, EndTime) > @EndTime THEN @EndTime ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, 1, EndTime) END
    FROM    HourlyCTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(HOUR, 1, StartTime) < @EndTime
)
SELECT  * 
INTO    #HourlyCTE
FROM    HourlyCTE
```

Then you can build your dynamic pivot columns using the `#HourlyCTE` as your source.  This also truncates the datetime to just `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), StartTime, 120))
FROM    #HourlyCTE
ORDER BY StartTime
```

Then you just have to build your pivot query into a varchar or nvarchar and execute it.

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT  *    
            FROM    (SELECT pc.PatientID,
                            pc.Unit,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), cte.StartTime, 120) as InTime
                     FROM   PatientCensus pc
                            JOIN #HourlyCTE cte ON pc.InDate <= cte.StartTime AND pc.OutDate >= cte.EndTime) t
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(PatientID)
                FOR InTime IN (' + @Columns + ')
            ) p'
EXEC(@SQL)
```